# How to call a workflow from a c# code

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a WF Written i want to invoke the workflow and get the result back from WF 
I have in and out parameters in work flow but i want to know how to call workflow from MY C# button click event.

Answer (score 2):

You need to become a WF "host"; more specifically, you use a WorkflowInvoker, or a WorkflowApplication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489463.aspx

In particular, if you need to get output values from the workflow, you can user the 
"Completed" event:

```
wfApp.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    val value = e.Outputs["MyValue"];
    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", value);
};
```